# Download picture via FTP with Java Firewall Issue

Tags: java, ftp, download, firewall

I am trying to download a file from a FTP server with Java. It only works when I disable the windows Firewall, I'm using windows 7.

Does anyone know a trick to solve this ? I would like my download to work with PC and MAC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch to passive FTP and see if that helps. How you do that depends on the library and/or server that you are using.

Passive protocol is more forgiving when it comes to firewalls if the server is properly configured.

Read more about passive and active FTP protocols on http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html and http://www.rhyshaden.com/ftp.htm

Hope it helps.